# How to make this query shorter and easier?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In this Laravel query any one can search those fields but the problem is when someone doesn't select all of the searchable fields it will give an error. Because the `whereIn` method doesn't get the value of the variable. If I check it with `if` condition then it will be a very big `sql`. So, is there any easy way to do this easily. My query is below.Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public function filter(Request $r){
    searchQuery = DB::table('jobs')->whereIn('division_id', $r->location)->whereIn('industrytype_id', $r->industry)->whereIn('category_id', $r->category)->whereIn('company_id', $r->company_id)->whereIn('created_at', $r->date)->whereIn('salary_range', $r->salary_range)->whereIn('jobType', $r->jobType)->orderByRaw($r->shortby)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WhereIn is a method where you should use an array. Your method should be look like:

```
public function filter(Request $r){  
    $searchQuery=DB::table('jobs')->where('division_id',$r->location)->where('industrytype_id',$r->industry)->where('category_id',$r->category)->where('company_id',$r->company_id)->where('created_at',$r->date)->where('salary_range',$r->salary_range)->where('jobType',$r->jobType)->orderBy($r->shortby)->get(); 
}
```

Comment: i know whereIn method wants array and $r->location is an array.No problem with where in

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to accept the (SQL) statement will get bigger. I guess you have something like this:?

```
public function filter(Request $r){
    $searchQuery = DB::table('jobs');

    if($r->location){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('division_id', $r->location);
    }
    if($r->industry){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('industrytype_id', $r->industry);
    }
    if($r->category){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('category_id', $r->category);
    }
    if($r->company_id){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('company_id', $r->company_id);
    }
    if($r->date){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('created_at', $r->date);
    }
    if($r->salary_range){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('salary_range', $r->salary_range);
    }
    if($r->jobType){
        $searchQuery->whereIn('jobType', $r->jobType);
    }

    $searchQuery->orderByRaw($r->shortby)->get();
}
```

If you do this really often you could write your own DB class which inherits the laravel DB class. And write some function in your own class like `$searchQuery->WhereInIfNotNull('industrytype_id', $r->industry);`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an scope to add every filter to the query. Define it on your model. Quick samples:

```
 public function scopeDivision($query,$searchParameter)
 {
    if(!is_null($searchParameter){
      return $query->whereIn('division_id', $searchParameter);
    }else{
      return $query;
    }
 }

 public function scopeIndustryType($query,$searchParameter)
 {
    if(!is_null($searchParameter){
      return $query->whereIn('industrytype_id', $searchParameter);
    }else{
      return $query;
    }
 }
```

Then back in your filter use it like this:

```
Job::division($r->location)
 ->industryType($r->industry)
 ->category($r->category)
 ->company($r->company_id)
 ->created($r->date)
 ->salaryRange($r->salary_range)
 ->jobType($r->job_type)
 ->orderByRaw($r->shortby)
->get()
```